Rewriting GET calls from JS script from an other JS script
I'm trying to convert some (old) dynamic sites to static pages. So far it works fine but I have some included JS scripts that build URL to load some other JS files, and the URL building is complicated (so just searching and replacing URL don't work, and I want a generic method).
I want to "rewrite" the GET calls performed from the JS in order to map them to my own (local) URL.
I tried using this script (added at the begin of the HTML source)
console.log("Script loaded");
// Override the open method of XMLHttpRequest to intercept all requests
var originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url) {
  console.log("Intercepted HTTP request: " + method + " " + url);
  originalOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
console.log("Script end");

in a script that is loaded at first in the HTML source. In the console (from webtools in Firefox) I can see the "Script loaded" at the begin of logs (and the "Script end"), but the "GET <url>" in the network logs associated later to the JS script are not intercepted.
I also tried
console.log("Script loaded");
const nativeFetch = window.fetch
window.fetch = async (input, init) => {
  const request = new Request(input, init);
  console.log("request happened!", request.method, request.url);
  return nativeFetch(input, init)
}
console.log("Script end");

with the same (lack) of result.
Note: both scripts come from Stack Overflow posts.
In the network console these GET look like:
(method) GET | (domain) <hostname> | (file) <URL path> | (initiator) <the infamous JS script> 

Both scripts don't log the console.log() directives, so it seems that nothing is intercepted.
Did I miss something? What is the right way to perform this? (if it is possible)
What I expect: I want to get a call to my JS function each time a script starts a GET call in order to intercept - and modify - the call to my own URL (that I still know).
To be more precise on the process: I download a HTML page from a site (to statify it). Then I download all the images, CSS and JS, rewriting URL (src, href…) to point to local version.
But when loading the page in Firefox with network console I can still see GET to JS pages that are from the original site URL. And the initiator of these GET is a JS script.
Rewriting the JS code is difficult and hazardous, so I'm trying to catch these GET (GET, here, is from the browser perspective) in order to re-route them to my local files.
Hope this is more clear.

How are you adding the scripts into the HTML file?

It is added inline, at the beginning of the HEAD section, when the initial page is downloaded. So it is really in the HTML file, not added dynamically with JS.

The functions you're patching are used for AJAX requests, which are used to load data. If you're loading JS dynamically, that's done by creating <script> elements dynamically, not with AJAX. I don't think there's a way to intercent that.

By looking at the JS that is triggering these other JS "GET" it seems that it do inserts <script> tags, yes.

@Barmar It was said "I want to 'rewrite' the GET calls performed from the JS in order to map them to my own (local) URL.". This means that the intention is indeed to intercept AJAX requests.

@KLASANGUI maybe my understanding - and my words - are not the good ones.

@KLASANGUI <script> and <link> tags use GET to fetch the scripts/CSS. So script = document.createElement('script'); script.src="URL"; document.head.appendChild(script); is a way to perform these GET requests from JS.

@Barmar GET requests (and alike) can't be performed directly because it's the browser prerogative. But everything else (that's not browser prerogatives) can be intercepted, including <script> tag injections.

@KLASANGUI I don't understand what you're saying. How would you intercept the GET requests that are performed as a result of injecting a script tag? It doesn't call fetch() or XMLHttpRequest.

@Barmar, you can just intercept the injection of <script> tags and replace their src attribute.

Can you show how to do that in your answer?

@Barmar Sure, I just did.

I don't really can determine what is making your approach to not work.
But I'll risk recommending not loading your interceptor script, but instead hardcode it directly in the html document.
Also, it would be good to attach your interceptor to top, self, window and globalThis.
Here's an example:
You only need the code inside the <script> tag in the HTML document.


console.log('Script loaded!');
{
  
  const exampleLink = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js';
  
  const myScriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  
  myScriptTag.src = exampleLink;
  document.head.appendChild(myScriptTag);
  
  setInterval
  (
    () =>
    {
      const newLink = document.createElement('a');
      const linkUrl = newLink.href = exampleLink + '?r=' + String(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
      
      generatedUrls.appendChild(newLink);
    },
    2000
  );
  
  fetch(exampleLink).then
  (
    Result =>
    {
      //console.log('Fetching Success:', exampleLink);
    }
  ).catch
  (
    Error =>
    {
      //console.log('Fetching Error:', Error.message);
    }
  );
  
  const myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  myRequest.addEventListener
  (
    'readystatechange', stateEvent =>
    {
      //console.log('XMLHttpRequest open() state changed. New state:', stateEvent.target.readyState);
      
      if ( stateEvent.target.readyState == 4 && stateEvent.target.status == 200 )
      {
        //console.log('XMLHttpRequest open() was successful.');
      }
    }
  );
  
  myRequest.addEventListener
  (
    'error', errorEvent =>
    {
      //console.log('XMLHttpRequest open() produced an error.');
      //console.log('Error:', errorEvent.target.error?.message ?? errorEvent.target.error);
    }
  );
  
  myRequest.open('GET', exampleLink, true);
  
}
console.log('Script ended!');
#observedUrls li
{
  list-style-type: none;
}
#generatedUrls a
{
  text-decoration: none;
}
#generatedUrls pre
{
  display: inline-block;
  break-before: never;
  break-after: never;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    
    <!-- This should be your first <script> tag in the document -->
    
    <script>
      
      ///// MAIN OBSERVER FUNCTION /////
      
      /**
       * The code of this function need to be changed completely
       * to achieve your purposes because it was made this way
       * for testing with the stacksnippets.net.
       */
      function observeUrl ( theUrl, theSource )
      {
        if ( ! theUrl?.length ) return;
        
        const newMessage = oldCreate.call(document, 'li');
        {
          console.log
          (
            (
              theSource.tagName
              ? ('<' + theSource.tagName.toLowerCase() + '>')
              : theSource.constructor.name
            )
            + ': ' + theUrl
          );
          
          newMessage.innerHTML =
          (
            '<strong>' +
            (
              theSource.tagName
              ? ('&lt;' + theSource.tagName.toLowerCase() + '&gt;')
              : theSource.constructor.name
            )
            + ':</strong> ' + theUrl
            .replaceAll('&', '&amp;')
            .replaceAll('<', '&lt;')
            .replaceAll('>', '&gt;')
          );
        }
        
        if ( ['interactive', 'complete'].includes(document.readyState) )
        {
          observedUrls.appendChild(newMessage);
        }
        
        else
        {
          const eventListener = readyEvent =>
          {
            if ( ['complete'].includes(document.readyState) )
            {
              observedUrls.appendChild(newMessage);
            }
          };
          
          document.addEventListener('readystatechange', eventListener);
        }
      }
      
      ///// OTHER OBSERVER FUNCTIONS /////
      
      function observeNew ( newElement )
      {
        if ( targetSubjects.elements.includes(newElement.tagName.toLowerCase()) )
        {
          observeElement(newElement);
          
          const superElement = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(newElement);
          
          for ( const theAttribute of targetSubjects.attributes )
          {
            const srcDescriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(superElement, theAttribute);
            
            if ( srcDescriptor )
            Reflect.defineProperty
            (
              newElement, theAttribute,
              {
                get: function ()
                {
                  return srcDescriptor.get.apply(newElement);
                },
                set: newValue =>
                {
                  observeUrl(newValue, newElement);
                  return srcDescriptor.set.apply(newElement, [newValue]);
                },
              }
            );
          }
        }
        
        return newElement;
      }
      
      function observeElement ( theElement )
      {
        for ( const theAttribute of targetSubjects.attributes )
        {
          if ( (typeof theElement[theAttribute] != 'undefined') && (theElement[theAttribute] !== '') )
          {
            observeUrl(theElement[theAttribute], theElement);
          }
        }
      }
      
      ///// OBSERVER CONFIGURATION /////
      
      console.clear();
      
      const targetSubjects =
      {
        attributes:
        [
          'action', 'data', 'formaction',
          'href', 'location', 'src', 'srcset'
        ],
        elements:
        [
          'a', 'area', 'audio', 'base', 'button',
          'canvas', 'embed', 'fencedframe', 'figure',
          'form', 'frame', 'frameset', 'iframe',
          'img', 'input', 'link', 'object', 'picture',
          'portal', 'script', 'source', 'track', 'video'
        ],
      };
      
      const oldCreate = document.createElement;
      const oldElement = Element;
      const oldFetch = fetch;
      const oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
      
      ///// OBSERVER AUTOLOAD /////
      
      targetSubjects.elements.forEach
      (
        tagName =>
        {
          for ( const theElement of document.querySelectorAll(tagName) )
          {
            observeNew(theElement);
          }
        }
      );
      
      ///// OBSERVER INJECTIONS /////
      
      function installGlobal ( theName, theValue )
      {
        const allContexts = {top, parent, self, window, globalThis};
        
        for ( const theContext in allContexts )
        {
          if ( allContexts[theContext] != null )
          {
            try
            {
              allContexts[theContext][theName] = theValue;
            }
            catch
            {
              console.log('Global installation failed:', theContext + '.' + theName);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      
      installGlobal
      (
        'Element', function newElement ()
        {
          const theElement = new oldElement(...arguments);
          
          if ( targetSubjects.elements.includes(theElement.tagName.toLowerCase()) )
          {
            observeNew(theElement);
          }
          
          return theElement;
        }
      );
      
      Document.prototype.createElement =
      document.createElement = function newCreate ( tagName, ...Arguments )
      {
        const theElement = oldCreate.apply(this, arguments);
        
        if ( targetSubjects.elements.includes(theElement.tagName.toLowerCase()) )
        {
          observeNew(theElement);
        }
        
        return theElement;
      }
      
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function newOpen ( theMethod, theUrl )
      {
        observeUrl(theUrl, this);
        
        return oldOpen.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      
      installGlobal
      (
        'fetch', function newFetch ( theUrl, ...Arguments )
        {
          observeUrl(theUrl, this);
          
          return oldFetch.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      );
      
      Reflect.setPrototypeOf(Element, oldElement);
      Reflect.setPrototypeOf(HTMLElement, Element);
      
      document.addEventListener
      (
        'readystatechange', readyEvent =>
        {
          if ( document.readyState == 'interactive' )
          {
            observeNew(document.querySelector('html'));
          }
        }
      );
      
    </script>
    
    <!-- Any other <script> tag goes after this -->
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <code>
      <strong>Observed URLs:</strong>
      <menu id="observedUrls"></menu>
      
      <div id="generatedUrls"></div>
    </code>
  </body>
  
</html>



EDIT: I just implemented the <script> tag interception. As this is just an example of how to do it, there's other tags that should be observed as well (like <a>, <link>, <img> and many others that could have the src or href attribute. You just need to slightly change the code to achieve that.

Thanks for the example. I tried it but still don't manage to get these GET (but I get some other one, so it's better). Looking at the JS code in question (too big to be inserted here) I can see near the line making the GET n.ajaxTransport("script", function(a) { and then b = d.createElement("script"), b.async = !0, a.scriptCharset && (b.charset = a.scriptCharset), b.src = a.url, b.onload = b.onreadystatechange = function(a, c) and at last c.insertBefore(b, c.firstChild) (where c is the 1st element of <head>

@YannickPerret I just implemented the <script> tag interception. PS.: this is just an example of how it works and only observes the <script> tag. You can just adjust alike for <link>, <img>, <a> and many other tags that could have src or href attributes.

@YannickPerret I implemented some search for elements that are already on the page as well.

Your last example seems to work. I can see <script> injections (with empty string) and then src modifications. I can also see some other strange insertions (such as a a tag without any URL). I will check this in practice - tonight, local time - but it's surely the good answer. Thanks

I still have some few things not intercepted. For example a got a a element that is created (I get the message in the console) but not the target value. From the JS script I can see var e=document.createElement(tag);   var id = 'async-buttons'; […]  e.type="text/javascript";e.id=id;  e.src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/async-buttons.js"; (and then it is inserted before the 1st script tag found. The src change does not trigger a message.

I still have some creations that are visible, but the creation (i.e. link) is with a "empty string" as href, and no set is visible (and the corresponding GET occurs just after). I added after the creation handling a MutationObserver on the new element, and with that I managed to get the href modification. The combination of the two allows me to have all the infos. What is strange is that for some other tags I get both creation and modification.

@YannickPerret I made major changes to the snippet. Would you like to test it?

I just tried your new code: it works as expected in my context. Thanks! A question: in between I started to look at MutationObserver. It seems that starting an observer on document.documentElement with childList: true and subtree: true allows to catch many things too. Is this also a valuable way or is it a bad idea?

@YannickPerret I tested with MutationObserver too... But I think the cost in performance is pretty high. The major problem is that I only managed to get the MutationObserver to observe child nodes. So, the callback in the MutationObserver object will execute for every element of the page at every change because they might have a child with the attribute you want do probe your URLs from. Add to that the scripts running on the page and your PC might burn. Note that the observer fires at every mutation (even css animations).

ok, noted. By the way, you wrote imput rather than input in the targetSubjects.elements array (you should correct it for future readers!). Thanks again.

@YannickPerret I made the change. Also, I added a restriction in observeUrl() for it to do nothing if the url is empty.
